# Can rockwool batting be used in termite heavy area under interior face of foundation wall in ground contact?

Tags: insulation, basement, termite, spray-foam, basement-insulation

I have a gap in my below-grade cellar ceiling and the interior face of my exterior foundation brick wall that I want to seal up.  I'm thinking of stuffing it with some Rockwool batting.  It was an area that was previously attacked by termites so I want to make sure it's termite resistant.

Would the Rockwool be pest resistant - against termites specifically and mice?

Should I use a fire block spray foam instead - even though it's a pretty large gap that would be difficult to bridge with foam?  Or would fire block foam also be vulnerable to termites?

I saw this [press release](https://www.rockwool.com/syssiteassets/o2-rockwool/documentation/technical-bulletins/residential/termiteresistance-technical-bulletin.pdf) from Rockwool which makes it sound like it would be a good choice.

> The results of the test, which are shown in the table below, indicate
> that the stone wool insulation proved to be termite resistant per this
> rigorous test making the material appropriate for use under conditions
> of very heavy termite hazard. The observations made by the laboratory
> during the trial noted that the termites initially investigated the
> stone wool but then covered with sand within the first week which
> is an avoidance behavior evidenced by termites that want to isolate
> something undesirable, such as inappropriate food material.
> [image]
> [image]

Comment: Think that link answers your question about using rock wool and termites.  This should protect the gap, but building materials above/under/to the side might not be.

Comment: Would that batting attract mice?

Comment: Mice and termites probably looking at 1/16 solid metal plate